# Why does God need Moshe to deliver the 10 plagues?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, bo, plagues-makkos, shlichus-agency, va-eira

Why does Hashem command Moshe to perform each macah (plague)? Hashem can perform the Macot himself (by sending malachim).

Comment: Perhaps a human emissary was needed to drive home the point to pharoah why this is happening (not just random events in nature) and to also make clear to the Israelites that Moshe was sent to redeem them.

Comment: Maybe Moshe needed Moshe to perform the makkot in order to a) boost his self-esteem and/or b) make him look more like a leader to the people

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, I like your response. However, aside from the stutter problem, he was a prince in Egypt before being banished.

Comment: But not a prince in Israel

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, aside from portraying his humbleness when conversing with God, do we ever learn that he had low self esteem?

Comment: Not self-esteem, necessarily, but he is not a natural leader.  When there's a problem, he runs away.  He doesn't take responsibility.  This is G-d's way of saying, "Moshe - *you* are responsible for getting folks out.  Do it." and a way of making Israel see that Moshe's responsible.  If G-d did it with melachim, imagine how much more rebellious we'da been to some johnny-come-lately from Midian who couldn't be bothered to act the role of leader.

Comment: I'd like to look up sources before posting an answer, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moshe was destined to be the one to bring down the torah, hence there needed to be no doubt that he was chosen by God.

this is also why he was speech impaired (so people would not say he smooth talked everyone into believing in him)

likewise it had to be in Egypt which was the world superpower for witchcraft (so that people would not say Moshe was a sorcerer and if he had done the plagues in Egypt, he would have been defeated). (And the final plague was on the 15th of Nissan which was astrologically the full moon of the month of the Ram and the strongest day of the [egyptian god](http://ancientties.com/thezodiac-aries-nissan-silktie.aspx).)

the bottom line is that the authenticity of the torah had to be demonstrated without a doubt - that it was from God. and since Moshe was the emmissary for delivering it, his authenticity also had to be established.

source Drashos Haran (forgot exact place)